# How do you create a Bash function that accepts files of a specific type as arguments?

Tags: bash, file, types, arguments, alias

So far, I know that you have to create a function in order to pass arguments.

However, how do you denote the type of the argument?

For instance, if you want to compile a Java class file and then run the resulting Java file (without having to type the file name twice to distinguish between the extensions each time), how do you let the function know that the names belong to files of different types?

Let's say this is our function:

```
compileAndRun()
{
    javac $1
    java  $2   # basically, we want to make this take the same argument
               # (because the names of the *.class and *.java files are the same)
}
```

So, instead of typing:

```
compileAndRun test.class test.java
```

We wanna just type this:

```
compileAndRun test
```

Any help along with any extraneous information you wanna throw in would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `file` command in some way to have Unix tell you what the type is (if it's known), but what you probably want to do is just to append `.java` to `$1` and `.class` to `$2`.  That'd be much easier than parsing the output from `file`.

Comment: There's little point in specifying both an input and output file name, since Java enforces that both file names match the name of the class defined inside (or am I misremembering? It's been a while since I used Java).

Answer (score 4):

Just use $1 twice. It is safer to connect the two commands with `&&`, so java is not run if the compilation is not successful.

```
function compile_n_run () {
    javac "$1".java && java "$1".class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to `bash` functions don't really have types; they are just strings, and it's up to you to use them appropriately. In this case, it's fairly simply to write a function which takes a Java source file, compiles it, and runs the resulting output.

```
compile_n_run () {
    source=$1
    expected_output="${source%.java}.class" 
    javac "$source" && java "$expected_output"
}

$ compile_n_run test.java
```

I chose to require the full Java source name because it's a little friendlier with auto-completion; you don't have to remove the `.java` from the command-line, rather you let the function do that for you. (And otherwise, this answer would be identical to [choroba's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343307/1126841)).

Comment: Earlier, I wrote back to you guys to let you know it works now; I guess my comment was deleted because I technically "answered" my own question. But, the code works like a charm and I'm getting a hang of Bash syntax. Thanks, fellas!